# Issue in SOAP response deseralization

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, axis

I have a SOAP response which i want to deseralize into SOAPApplicationResult object. I have succeeded to get type NS1 and NS2 from the response but facing issues while deseralizing some NS3 types from the response. 
below is the code i am using to deseralize and SOAP response.

```
    String fileName = "com/servicebus/thirdparty/response.xml";
    String response = SystemUtil.loadFileAsString(fileName);    
    org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer server = new org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer();
    MessageContext msgContext = new MessageContext(server);
    registerMessage(msgContext);
    java.io.Reader reader = new java.io.StringReader(response);
    DeserializationContext dser = new DeserializationContext(new org.xml.sax.InputSource(reader), msgContext,
            Message.RESPONSE);
    dser.parse();   
    SOAPEnvelope env = dser.getEnvelope();
    RPCElement rpcElem = (RPCElement) env.getFirstBody();
    MessageElement struct = rpcElem.getRealElement();
    Iterator childElements = struct.getChildElements();
    while (childElements.hasNext())
    {
        org.apache.axis.description.ParameterDesc param;
        MessageElement next = (MessageElement) childElements.next();

        SOAPApplicationResult objectValue = (SOAPApplicationResult) next.getValueAsType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
                "SOAPApplicationResult","http://soap.xxxx.yyyy.com"), SOAPApplicationResult.class);
        String serializeAxisObject = AxisObjectUtil.serializeAxisObject(objectValue, true, true);
    }
```

When i remove OccupationLoading and PersonObjectList types from the response then its getting deseralized but with these two its not working. it is giving error "org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.webservices.thirdparty.generated.infexpert.SOAPPersonResult - PersonObjectList". I am giving QName (new javax.xml.namespace.QName("SOAPApplicationResult" ,"http://soap.xxxx.yyyyy.com")) for NS2.  It seems i have to map multiple QNames to the context but dont know how to do it.

this is the SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:NS1="urn:ABCDSoapProviderIntf-IABCDSOAPProvider">
        <NS1:calculateResponse xmlns:NS2="http://soap.xxxx.yyyyy.com"
            xmlns:NS3="http://soap.xxxx.zzzz.com/">
            <return xsi:type="NS2:SOAPApplicationResult">
                <ErrorMessage xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <Result xsi:type="xsd:string" />
                <PersonResults xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"
                    SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:SOAPPersonResult[1]">
                    <item xsi:type="NS3:ABCDSoapPersonResult">
                        <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">1245245</ID>
                        <Result xsi:type="xsd:string">Doc</Result>
                        <RuleResults xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"
                            SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:SOAPRuleResult[1]">
                            <item xsi:type="NS2:SOAPRuleResult">
                                <Result xsi:type="xsd:string">Doc</Result>
                                <Notice xsi:type="xsd:string">A Document is required</Notice>
                            </item>
                        </RuleResults>
                        <ProductResults xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"
                            SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:SOAPProductResult[1]">
                            <item xsi:type="NS3:ABCDSOAPProductResult">
                                <Result xsi:type="xsd:string">Offer</Result>
                                <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">Some Id</ID>
                                <RuleResults xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"
                                    SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:SOAPRuleResult[1]">
                                    <item xsi:type="NS2:SOAPRuleResult">
                                        <Result xsi:type="xsd:string">Offer</Result>
                                        <Notice xsi:type="xsd:string">Standard</Notice>
                                        <Reasons xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:SOAPReason[0]" />
                                    </item>
                                </RuleResults>
                                <OccupationLoading xsi:type="NS3:SOAPPermanentLoading">
                                    <BeginAfter xsi:type="xsd:int">0</BeginAfter>
                                    <BeginEnd xsi:type="xsd:int">0</BeginEnd>
                                </OccupationLoading>
                            </item>
                        </ProductResults>
                        <PersonObjectList xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]">
                            <item>Z001</item>
                            <item>E6679</item>
                        </PersonObjectList>
                    </item>
                </PersonResults>
            </return>
        </NS1:calculateResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```